# Openquery for serverlink exceedes 8000 characters

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, linked-server

I want to create a view as follows:

```
CREATE view [dbo].[test] as 
SELECT TEST.* 
FROM OPENQUERY([MyServerLink],'LONGSELECTQUERY') as TEST;
```

The *SELECT* statement exceeds 8000 characters long which gives me that error:

> SQL Error [103] [S0001]: The character string that starts with 'SELECT ...' is too long. Maximum length is 8000.

How can I overcome that and create my view?

Comment: Have you tried a shorter query string? Maybe creating a view on the remote server that encapsulates the majority of the code that's in your current query string?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning yes, shorter works, nevertheless i cannot make it shorter. Is there any othey way around?

Comment: As mentioned earlier, most (if not all) of the code in the select statement could probably be used to create a view on the remote server, then the select statement in `openquery()` can be pared back to just something like `select column,...,list from NameOfRemoteView`.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a temporary table on the linked server and then use the temporary table

Example (MySQL)

```
EXEC('DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS TEMP_LONGSELECTQUERY') AT MyServerLink
EXEC('
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE TEMP_LONGSELECTQUERY AS
    LONGSELECTQUERY
') AT MyServerLink
SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(MyServerLink, 'SELECT * FROM TEMP_LONGSELECTQUERY')
```

But, if the linked server is also a MSSQL Server you can make a select refering to the `Server.Database.Schema.Table`:

```
SELECT
    /******/
FROM MyServerLink.master.dbo.xxx x
join  MyServerLink.master.dbo.yyy y /*****/
```